# How can I install a Node.js module under $HOME/bin

Tags: node.js, npm

The question title is self-expanatory, but just to make more clear...

With `npm install -g` I can install anything globaly, what turns it in an application command. But, in GNU/Linux, this requires root access, so, what if I want install something as a command, but only for the current logged user, and not needing root access?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @brian-glaz tip I managed to do like this:

Create a `~/.npmrc` file with the folowing content

```
prefix=~/
```

Notice that it must be lowercase `prefix`.

You can check the paths as follows:

```
paulo.goncalves@paulogoncalves:~$ npm -g root
/home/paulo.goncalves/lib/node_modules
paulo.goncalves@paulogoncalves:~$ npm -g bin
/home/paulo.goncalves/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but according to the docs, you should be able to create a `~/.npmrc` file with `PREFIX=$HOME/bin`

https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html

Comment: Didn't work. Not exaclty as you said, but .npmrc does the trick. It also can be set throgh `npm config set prefix`.